# How to pass parameters into url after render() in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, url-routing, google-search

I'm trying to use `Google's Custom Search Engine` product to display results from a query on a page for a personal web app.

How `CSE` is working is that it takes parameters from the URL as search terms: i.e., `www.mydomain.com/results.html?q=hello+world` would return results for a "hello world" query on the page. You put some `JS` code they give you on your page, so it's a bit of a black box.

However, with `URL` `routing` and `render()` on `Django`, I'm guessing the basics is that `www.mydomain.com/results` gets routed to a `views.results` calls which `renders results.html` as `www.mydomain.com/results`.

What is the best-practice for submitting a query through a form, and passing it to `www.mydomain.com/results.html?q=hello+world` instead of redirecting to `www.mydomain.com/results` and having `Django` render the results/html file?

Sorry, I'm relatively new. I can try to piece things together, but I feel there has got to be a very efficient way of handling this situation. Thanks for understanding

Comment: show some code brother

Answer (score 0):

You're completely overthinking this. There's nothing different here from any other request: the form submits via GET to the results view, the view gets the search query from `request.GET["q"]` or wherever, does the search and passes the results to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, but I'm not sure that will work.

First, the Google CSE JS code looks like this:

```
  <div class="container">
     <gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
  </div>
```

I'm not sure if it uses the request.GET["q"] method.

Second, I want to process the "q" parameter with additional things beyond what the form sends. Does that make sense?

I want the workflow to be like this:

```
    query = {'keywords':request.GET.get('k'),
         'urls':request.GET.get('u'),
         'collections':request.GET.getlist('c'),
         'filetypes':request.GET.getlist('f')
         }
    query_final = create_query(query) # Some other function
    return render(request,'app_search/results.html') # Need to go to domain.com/results.html?q=blahblahblah
```